# How to add class if single tag?

Tags: html, twig, symfony

I have 4 `<li></li>`, which are showed or not.

```
{% if li == 1 %}{% endif %}
```

How to add class if only one (single) `<li></li>` is showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are display a collection of items you can check the length of the array. As example:

```
{% set elems = ['1','2'] %}
{# {% set elems = ['1'] %} #}

{%for elem in elems %}
  <li{% if elems|length == 1 %} class="single" {% endif %}>
    {{elem}}
  </li>
{%endfor%}
```

[Here a working example](https://twigfiddle.com/n0j1ey)

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this slightly differently by applying the style only when the element is the single child of it's parent (only one is rendered)

```
ul li:only-child {
property: value;
}
```

[link to w3schools article here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_only-child.asp)

Comment: make sence, thank you. Any way to make it with twig?

Answer (score 1):

```css
li:first-child {
    property: value;
}
```